# React Native Navigation Undefined is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying hard to get the Node Package react-native-navigation to work in my project. But, when I try to run my application I'm greeted with a nasty error I can't seem to track down. Help is appreciated.

Error:

[image: errorr]

index.js:

```
import Navigation from 'react-native-navigation';
import SideBar from './sidebar';
import Meetups from './meetups';

export default function() {
    Navigation.registerComponent('inbetween.sidebar', () => SideBar);
    Navigation.registerComponent('inbetween.meetups', () => Meetups);
}
```

App.js:

```
import Navigation from 'react-native-navigation';
import registerScreens from './screens';

registerScreens();

export default class App {

}

Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
  screen: {
    screen: 'inbetween.meetups',
    title: 'Meetups',
    navigatorStyle: {},
    navigatorButtons: {}
  },
  drawer: {
    left: {
      screen: 'inbetween.sidebar',
      passProps: {}
    },
    disableOpenGesture: false
  },
  passProps: {},
  animationType: 'slide-down'
});
```

index.android.js

```
import App from './src/App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

SideBar:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class SideBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Text>Navigation List Here</Text> 
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export default SideBar;
```

Meetups:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class Meetups extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style>
        <Text>Meetup List Here</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export default Meetups;
```

Comment: Have you linked the native dependencies to the project correctly? https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android

Comment: @hyb175 Yes I have completed those instructions. Even double checked I did it right by comparing it to their example project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `Navigation` like this:
`import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';`

Comment: Such an obvious catch. Thank you so much for pointing that out. Also, for anyone else who may reference the code I pasted in my question; make sure you import AppResistry from react-native.